# Let's consider the set $F$ of all numbers of type $r + s \sqrt{2}$ where $r, s \in \mathbb Q$. $F \subset \mathbb R$...

Tags: real-analysis

> Let's consider the set $F$ of all numbers of type $r + s \sqrt{2}$ where $r, s \in >\mathbb Q$. $F \subset \mathbb R$.
> Let's define subsets of $F$. Let $P \subset F$ such that $P = F \cap \mathbb R^+$ >positive numbers of $F$.
>
> Let's define the subset $ B \subset F$ by
> $r + s \sqrt{2} \in B \iff r - s \sqrt{2} \in P$.
>
> Using the order relationship defined above compare the numbers $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $y = >-1 + 3\sqrt{2}$ and justify.

we have B is as follows $r + s \sqrt{2}, x = 0 + 1\sqrt{2}$

we have P is as follows $r - s \sqrt{2}, y = -1 - (-3)\sqrt{2} = -1 + 3\sqrt{2}$

then $x \lt y$ ?

$r - s \sqrt{2} \in P$ but P is positive

so

if r, s $\gt$ 0,and $r \gt s\sqrt{2}$, then P is positive$

if r,s $\lt$ 0, and $r \lt s\sqrt{2}$, then P is positive$

if r $\gt$ 0, s $\lt$ 0, then P is positive$

$r + s \sqrt{2} \in B$

so

if r, s $\gt$ 0,then B is positive

if r,s $\lt$ 0, then B is not positive

if r $\lt$ 0, s $\gt$ 0, and  $r \lt s\sqrt{2}$ then B is positive

if r $\gt$ 0, s $\lt$ 0, and $r \gt s\sqrt{2}$ then B is positive

I think I did not get it.

I'm having trouble seeing P $\ne$ B.

Sorry, completely lost.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please ask one clear question. It would be nice to fix the many typos involving the sign `>`, why do you insist to format like that?! Also, typing `if r, s $\gt$ 0,and $r \gt s\sqrt{2}$,`  makes the story look bad, please enclose **all** math relations between dollars, so `if $r, s \ge 0$, and $r \ge s\sqrt{2}$,` would look better. For the question... which is exactly the question, please state one an only one clear question. In the statement, $P$ is the positive cone in the field $\Bbb Q(a)$, $a^2=2$, w.r.t. mapping $a\to+\sqrt2\in\Bbb R$, and $B$ same for $a\to-\sqrt 2\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: The two cones differ, for instance $\sqrt 2\in P$, but it is not in $B$. Same for $1+\sqrt 2$, or $-1+\sqrt 2$. But there are also elements in the field, that are "totally positive", i.e. they are positive when mapped to $\Bbb R$ by using both embeedings. For instance $10000+a$, since in $\Bbb R$ both elements $10000\pm \sqrt 2$ are positive. To compare two different elements $x,y$ w.r.t. the positive cone $P$ take the difference $x-y$ and see if it is in $P$, if yes, then $x>_P y$, else the converse is holding.

Comment: @dan_fulea sorry I don't think I understand. -$\sqrt{2}$ should not belong to P and $\sqrt{2}$ should belong to B ? since r + s\sqrt{2} \in B and r - s\sqrt{2} \in P. In my specific case the sum would be $ xy = (\sqrt{2}) - (-1 + 3\sqrt{2}) = 1 - 2\sqrt{2}$ which according to what you said is are you in B? so $y \gt x$?